# Distributed Computing Setup

Tags: cloud-computing

Anyone know a good system I could use to setup multiple computers to work together as one?  I am hoping that there is something that I can setup pretty easily.

I was wanting to use some slower hardware working together to do stuff like C++ compiling, video rendering, etc...

Comment: Can you expand on "work together as one" (e.g. what tasks)?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Work together to process as one computer -- for example: compile a c++ program.

Comment: [Visualization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_visualization) is not quite the right term then (that would mean drawing graphs of how it works, basically). Isn't the term you're looking for rather [distributed computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_computing)?

Comment: @Izzy Thanks for the edit suggestion! Now all I need is a good tag...

Comment: You've found a good one. Think of your own personal cloud :)

Comment: @Izzy Yea... It's the best I could come up with, and I don't have the rep here to make a new one...

Answer (score 1):

For a reasonably quick to get running option you could take a look at the various python based systems to allow remote execution of code on other machines, there is quite a list [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DistributedProgramming).

I would strongly suggest reading some material on Distributed Computing as it is a **big** subject and there is both a science and an art to structuring problems so that they can run quicker on multiple systems.